# How do I re-enable the DCOM service, after I disabled it?

Tags: windows-xp, services, system-restore

Okay, so I disabled the DCOM service.  Now, lots of stuff doesn't work, including the Windows Services utility!  I'm running Windows XP Professional.  How can I re-enable the DCOM service?  Can this be done via the registry (i.e. RegEdit)?  Also, I'm willing to do a system restore to fix this, but I can't get to it.  I usually access the system restore feature through Windows Help, but Help isn't working. :(  Is there another way to get to it?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to try a system restore from the command line.  Brb in a few (I hope)....

Comment: famous last words? :)

Comment: my f5 is getting warm too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it took a while, but I ended up having to do a System Repair using the OEM install CD.  Apparently, something was corrupted.  The repair seems to have fixed things.  Thanks for the  help everyone!

Comment: Thanks for the update! Makes sense, post if you have any more questions ;)

Answer (score 1):

`1.` Start > Run > dcomcnfg.exe

`2.` If you are running Windows XP or Windows Server 2003, perform these additional steps:

> 1. Click the Component Services node under Console Root.
> 2. Open the Computers folder.
> 3. For the local computer, right-click My Computer, and then click
>      Properties.
> 4. For a remote computer, right-click Computers folder, point to New, and
>      then click Computer.
> 5. Type the computer name.
> 6. Right-click the computer name, and then click Properties.

`3.` Click the Default Properties tab.

`4.` Click to select the Enable Distributed COM on this Computer check box.

`5.` If you want to set more properties for the computer, click Apply to enable DCOM. Otherwise, click OK to apply the changes and quit Dcomcnfg.exe.

`6.` Restart the operating system for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Beat me to it :p, for completeness sake: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825750

Comment: Unfortunately, dialog boxes are no longer working, so clicking on Properties isn't doing anything.  Any other ideas?  Any thoughts on how to get to System Restore without going through Help?

Comment: c:\windows\system32\restore\rstrui

Comment: What happens when you change HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\OLE "EnableDCOM" to "Y"? (backup registry first).

Answer (score 0):

Try NET START from a CMD prompt, find the service in the list, then do NET START "service name"; worth a try, but it sounds like the problem is a little deeper than DCOM.

Comment: The DCOM service doesn't appear in the list.  You could be right; just prior to this I also installed a bunch of Windows updates via their new "Microsoft Update."  Do you have any ideas on how to launch System Restore without going through help?  Thanks.

Comment: c:\windows\system32\restore\rstrui